# What would be the equivalent C# for this VB.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

When I create a new empty web application project in VB.net I see the file `Application.myapp` under My Project.

The same file does not appear in C#. So what does get created in C# project which is equivalent to this file?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of Application.myapp in C# is app.config